# How can I make radio buttons with more values? And how do I select them via body parser

Tags: html, body-parser

Is it possible to have 2 values on a radio button? If so how can I use them via Node Js and the body parser element. I also have the express addon

```
<input id="Celcius"type="radio" name="unit" value="metric">
```

But it also should have another value of "Celcius". How can I choose between those to values when it is possible?
I want something like that:

```
<input id="Celcius"type="radio" name="unit" value="metric", "Celcius">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this example https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio it's pretty easy to get several values on radio buttons the key is that all radio element have the same name attribute  so in node/express you retrieve the unit query parameter. Please edit your post and tag it html not nodejs your question is more about html.

Comment: this is unfortunaitaly not working because in there is no part about multiple values

Comment: you want a single button with multiple values right? It's not the way it work you can have radio group with multiple values.